# Double Integral: Find the flux through a surface. Check my answer

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus, vectors

The Question:
Let $\Sigma$ be the portion of $z=16-x^2-y^2$ inside the cylinder $r=2cos\theta$ and with upward orientation. Draw a picture of $\Sigma$ and find the rate at which the fluid $\mathbf F = x\mathbf j$ is flowing through $\Sigma$

Please check my solution. I attempted it using an oriented surface integral

The picture is a upside down paraboloid with bounds of a circle with radius $2$ centered at $x=1$

I first parametrized the surface.

$\mathbf r = x \mathbf i + y \mathbf j + (16-x^2-y^2 )\mathbf k$

Next I found the cross product: $\mathbf r_x \times \mathbf r_y = 2x \mathbf i + 2y \mathbf j + \mathbf k$

The cross product is oriented upward.

And my final integral is:

$\int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2}\int_0^{2cos\theta}\ 2r^3cos\theta sin\theta\, drd\theta$

Comment: Perhaps is useful the parametrization $\vec{\phi}(r,\theta)=r\cos\theta \vec{i}+r\sin\theta \vec{j}+(16-r^2) \vec{k}$. Then I unerstand (I've studied mathematics years ago, and currently I am tried refreshs it) folllowing  http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/CalcIII/SurfaceIntegrals.aspx that should be compute $\int\int_{D}(r\cos\theta)\sqrt{5}rdrd\theta$, where $D$ is your integration domain. If you do new computations please tell me.

Comment: You should check your cross product, Using your parametrization I got the same answer as in my question. I believe my integral is correct

Comment: Thanks @Darklink9110 I am trying refresh my mathematics, then I don't sure a full answer, but $\partial\phi/\partial r=(\cos\theta,\sin\theta,-2r)$ and $\frac{\partial\phi}{\partial\theta}=(-r\sin\theta,r\cos\theta,0)$, and my cross-product holds, with cited norm. I don't know give a good answer to your question, but as the sky is blue since I don't recognize the form of jacobian in your computations by a comparision with cited reference in the link, when I do the change to polars, your jacobian should be wrong. Thanks.

Comment: I've started a bounty over your question, I hope that we learn with the answer. It will be useful too to me, to refresh my mathematics.  Thanks.

Comment: I'm sorry @Darklink9910, you are rigth, I hope that it was succesful to you to check your good solution.

Comment: If one day you need open a bounty, it is, you need an asnwer for a problem quickly (perhaps for a preparation of your exams) and you don't know how obtain the answer you can tell me with a comment and I will try open the bounty. Good look! @Darklink9110

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you did looks right!

**Method 1**
Parametrize as you did:
$$
x=x, \quad y=y, \quad z=16-x^2-y^2,
$$

with

- $(x,y)\in D=\{(r,\theta)\;|\; -\pi/2 \le \theta \le \pi/2, 0\le r \le 2\cos\theta \}$,
- $r_x\times r_y =(1,0,-2x)\times (0,1,-2y)=(2x,2y,1)$, which indeed is correctly oriented.

It follows that your flux equals
$$
\phi=\iint_{\Sigma}\vec{F}\cdot d\vec{S}=\iint_{D}(0,x,0)\cdot(2x,2y,1) dA=\iint_{D}2xy\; dA=\int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2}\int_0^{2\cos\theta}2r^3\cos\theta\sin\theta\;drd\theta,
$$
which yields $\phi=0$.

**Method 2** Use your second parametrization (in cylindrical coordinates). It will give you the exact same integral 
$$\int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2}\int_0^{2\cos\theta}2r^3\cos\theta\sin\theta\;drd\theta.
$$

I think it is slightly better to use cartesian coordinates for parametrization as computing $r_x \times r_y$ is always easy if $x$ and $y$ are your parameters. It may not always be the case with parameters $r$ and $\theta$.

**Method 3** 
Note that your surface $\Sigma$ is an open surface, but it is possible to close it with the plane $z=16-2x$. Indeed, the cylinder $x^2+y^2=2x$ intersects $z=16-x^2-y^2$ at $z=16-2x$. Let $S$ be the portion of this plane that closes $\Sigma$ underneath. A normal unitary vector of $S$ is given by $\frac{1}{\sqrt5}(2,0,-1)$. By the divergence theorem:

$$
\phi = \iint_{\Sigma\cup S}\vec{F}\cdot d\vec{S}-\iint_{ S}\vec{F}\cdot d\vec{S}=\iiint_E div(\vec{F})\; dV - \iint_{ S}(0,x,0)\cdot \frac{1}{\sqrt5}(2,0,-1) \;dS=0-0=0.
$$

Note how the orientation of $\frac{1}{\sqrt5}(2,0,-1)$ (oriented towards z<0) is compatible with the divergence theorem.
The nature of the field $(0,x,0)$ kind of hints that this method should work, as the divergence will be 0, but computing the second part of the integral (the flux through $S$) can be tricky depending on the surface. But sometimes it requires no computing at all, like here!

Comment: Now, I've read only the first and I find my mistake. After I will read remains solutions, and remains as a good reference to me. Now I recognize too the last, when you uses the divergence theorem. I will choose your answer in 19 hours, it succesful to me, was a bad day to me, but I learn this from your hands and too from Darklink9110. Very thanks much @Kuifje